# PhpmyAdmin Primary column moved

Tags: phpmyadmin

My primary column (the one wih "Delete, Copy, Modify, Select") which is normaly at the begin of the table (first from left) goes at the end (extrem right). I don't know how and how to reset it ?

I'm talking about this column : [image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those you still wonder the reason is because it's a new feature from PhpmyAdmin. I'm still looking for the release note and the version when it appears to quote official source.

This is probably cause by my hosting service because when I check the version i get :

```
**phpMyAdmin**

Version : OVH
Documentation
Wiki
Site officiel
Contribuer
Obtenir de l'aide
Liste des changements
```

I contacted the technical support and they told me it's a PhpmyAdmin feature with the new version not a "bug".

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about when clicking the Browse button, you can go to the Structure tab to "Move columns" (but there's no reason I know why this order would have changed; normally it's eternally in the order you create it).

If you've run some SQL code to get the result, just reorder your code. Instead of, for instance, `` SELECT `first_name`, `last_name`, `actor_id` FROM `actor` `` you can make it `` SELECT `actor_id`, `first_name`, `last_name` FROM `actor` ``.

Hope that clear it up.

Comment: No Isaac it does not work because this column doesn't appear as a "movable column". I added an image to my post to clarify my question. Thanks !